# How do I see who's online to my linked Gchat and Facebook Chat in Messages?

Tags: macos

I had Google Chat and Facebook Chat linked to iChat, but since I upgraded to Mountain Lion I can't see who's online through the bar that used to display along side messaging window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the window menu you can access all the same contact lists as before (or a unified list if you chose that within Messages preferences)

Command + [a number] is the shortcut to open/close these windows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar shows your list of open chats. When someone is offline, the text "*Offline*" shows under their name:

[image]

This also depends on whether you have iMessage-enabled contact information for those people — it seems that if you do, they never appear as Offline.

(Also note that the buddy list window still works well for seeing who's online!)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same inconvenience but then found it. It's the exact same buddy list you had in iChat:

Command + 1 
Or Window - Buddies.